# Azure table storage - search by rowkey only to get user by username for logging in

Tags: azure-table-storage

When a user logs into the system I'm building, I need to get the user by username in order to:

1. See if the user exists
2. See if the hashed password for that user matches what the user entered

The problem is that I only have the username and password at that point. It seems silly to have to ask for last name or anything else I might use as the partition key.

That being said, I know that it's a bad idea to search by rowkey only and I'm not even sure if you can using the TableOperation.Retrieve(partitionKey, rowKey) method (I've tried passing null as the partition key but Azure politely says no).

Does anyone have a good idea? What have you all been doing in this scenario?

thanks,
Colin

Comment: In this case, you can simply use something generic for the partition key right? Maybe just "users". If you really need to split them up, maybe you can choose the partition key based on the username. For example by first letter of the username.

Comment: @hatcyl. It won't help to use the "users" for the partition key since the query will already be searching only the user table. It's funny that you mention using the first letter of the username. That's what I had decided to go with yesterday. If you post it as an answer, I'll mark it as the correct answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't post comments yet but i suggest that instead of using the first letter use something that really make a good partition of your set. Ex: 3 letters you will have 26*26*26=17576 possible partitions for your set of users if you have a few users for you app then you can only use 1 or 2 letters.

This will improve your performance when you have a big number of users